# Episode of TV show where nobody was allowed to be smart

Tags: story-identification, mind-control

At some point in (I think) the 90s, I saw an episode of something like Outer Limits or Twilight Zone where nobody was allowed to have more than average intelligence. Smarter children had to wear headsets which inhibited them from being too intelligent, administering minor electric shocks if intellectual thought was detected.

I can remember a final (or near final) scene of somebody watching his suicide and being upset but not remembering why because of the headset.

Can anybody identify the show and episode?

Comment: Very likely to be an adaptation of "Harrison Bergeron" by Kurt Vonnegut, originally published 1961.

Comment: Indeed. And [repeatedly made into films and TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Bergeron#Adaptations)

Comment: Given the time frame, it is likely the 1995 TV movie version of "Harrison Bergeron" mentioned above. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Bergeron_(film)

Comment: It looks very much like Harrison bergeron.  I can remember a final (or near final) scene of somebody watching his suicide and being upset but not remembering why because of the headset.

Comment: From the title, I was REALLY hoping this would be Futurama's "The Day the Earth Stood Stupid".

Comment: The pedant in me cannot suppress the urge to point out that it is impossible that everybody is of "average" intelligence or lower.

Comment: @xLeitix in fact, in the story nobody is supposed to be of less than average anything either.

Comment: A friend at work was asking me about this the other day as well... A show she saw in her youth, in black and white, "maybe Twilight Zone"... It wasn't the 80s Twilight Zone, it was decades before that. She also said the man in it would get electric shocks if he thought of anything too smart.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks very much to the people who suggested [*Harrison Bergeron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Bergeron_(film)) (1995).

The memory of somebody watching his death but - wearing a headset - being too stupid to know why they are upset (Harrison's father) is strong.  Also the final scene of rebellious youths taking off their headsets and watching his speech.

Answer (score 6):

"Examination Day" is the first segment of the sixth episode from the first season (1985–86) of the television series The Twilight Zone. The segment is based on the short story "Examination Day" by Henry Slesar.  It does not match your description exactly (no electric shocks), but it is similar enough that you may be confusing aspects of it with something else.

There's a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examination_Day) that describes it better than I can.

Comment: Good call but it really looks like Harrison Bergeron